# Modules Not Found - I cannot externally run a .py file developed using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm to develop a python project, which uses an external library called win10toast. I have installed win10toast using PyCharm. However, when I tried to run the .py file using cmd (i.e Externally running the python file), an error shows up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast'.
```

I have python 3.6.4. I installed win10toast using PyCharm.

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
```

I expect the program to run without any error, but currently I am getting the ModuleNotFound error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pycharm but it might keep libraries locally to not interfere with your system. Maybe from the terminal you can run `pip install win10toast` before executing your .py file.

Comment: I would suggest that you not use PyCharm to install packages, at least if the result deviates from doing a "pip install" at the command line.  I see no reason to involve PyCharm in configuring Python installations.  It's just asking for trouble.I admit that I'm not sure just what I'm talking about, as I've been using PyCharm for years and have never once doing anything but installing Python modules at the command line so that I'm sure right where they're going.

Answer (score 2):

Python can be tricky to run properly because it is sensitive to where you installed your dependencies (such as external libraries and packages). If you installed Python to one directory, but accidentally installed the external library to another directory, when you run your .py program, it will be unable to call from the external library because it doesn't exist in the same library that Python is running from.

Lookup where you installed Python on your computer and then find where you installed the external library. Once your find where you installed the external library, move its entire package content to the same directory where Python is installed. Or better yet, reinstall the external library with pip into the same directory as Python.

If you're on Mac, Python and its related dependencies are usually stored somewhere in /User/bin. If you're on Windows, it will be stored somewhere in your C:// directory (possibly somewhere in C:\Users\username\Local\AppData). If you're on Linux, it will be stored somewhere in /usr/bin. Whatever you do, don't move Python from wherever it is because sometimes that can mess up your system for certain operating systems like Mac, which comes with its own version of Python (Python 2.7 I believe, which is outdated anyway).

Lastly, you may have two different versions of Python on your computer, which is common; Python 2.7 and Python 3+. If you wrote your program in one version, but ran it from the other, the external library can only be called from whichever Python version you installed it to. Try running your .py program with python3 instead of python (or vice versa) and see what happens. If it works with one python version over the other, that tells you that the external library is installed in the other version's directory.

That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you not use PyCharm to install packages, at least not 
if the result deviates in the slightest from doing a "pip install" at the command line.  I see no reason to involve PyCharm in configuring Python installations.  It's just asking for trouble.

I admit that I'm not familiar with the practice I'm suggesting you avoid.  I've been using PyCharm since pretty much the week it came out (was an avid user of the IntelliJ Python plugin before that), and have never once considered doing anything but installing Python modules at the command line.  That way, I'm sure right where those modules are going (into which base Python install or venv).  Also, I know I'm doing all that I can to minimize the differences that I might see between running code in PyCharm and running it at the command line.  I'm making my suggestion based solely on this practice having never gone wrong for me.

I have multiple base Python versions installed, and dozens of venvs defined on top of those.  PyCharm is great at allowing me to indicate which of these I want to apply to any project or Run/Debug configuration, and utilizing them seamlessly.  But agin, I administer these environments at the command line exclusively.

I still experience issues in switching between the command line and PyCharm in terms of one module referencing others in a single source tree.  My company has come up with a simple solution to this that insures that all of our Python scripts still run when moving away from PyCharm and its logic for maintaining the Python Path within a project.  I've explained the mechanism before on S.O.  I'd be happy to find that if anyone is interested.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for clarifying this. I always thought the "virtual environment" in PyCharm is the real Python environment, now I know that they are two different things and a lot of things starts to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The library `win10toast` installed in the directory: `YOUR_PYCHARM_WORKSPACE\PycharmProjects\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\venv\Lib\site-packages`
but when you are running your program using *cmd*, pycharm interpreter uses site-packages directory that you installed python at there. for Ex: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`
So, you can install the `win10toast` library to this windows directory using **pip**.